# adding 2D array rows with Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to add the int's from each row of a 2D array and then find which row has highest total. The size of the array is variable, being declared by the user at the beginning of the program.

```
// a 2D Array named score is made. Its axis' are maxComp and maxRound       

int[][] score = new int[maxComp][maxRound];

//Player x is called

for (int x = 0; x < maxComp; x++) {
    System.out.println("Player " + (x+1));
    //Player x enters all their scores
    for (int r = 0; r < maxRound; r++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your score for round " + (r + 1) );
        score [x][r] = in.nextInt();
    } 
}
```

now i wish to find the highest score form each player (row). I'm not sure if I should be using a method.  Or which method I should use.  I slightly understand how to add things from an array, but I don't understand how to add from rows that vary in number each time the program is run.

Comment: Can't you just loop over the scores and store the largest in a variable for comparison?

Comment: You could create an array that holds the best score for each player: `int[] bestScores = new int[maxComp];`. Then fill this array for each player by looping through his scores and comparing it with the already found bestScore (bestScore has to be initialized with the lowest possible score before).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable such as int maxScore. Then inside the first for loop you set it equal to 0 to clear it for each player. In the second for loop you can then do

```
if(r == 0)
    maxScore = score[x][r]
else if(maxScore < score[x][r])
    maxScore = score[x][r]
```

This will give you the maxScore for each player. Then you can either store that variable or print it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int x = 0; x < maxComp; x++) {
    int maxScore = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < maxRound; r++) {
        int currentScore = score [x][r];
        if(currentScore > maxScore){
            maxScore = currentScore;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Player " + x + " max Score is " + maxScore);
}
```